# Why Vala Compiler Throws Errors When Using Question Mark (?) Operator?

Tags: vala, gtk4

I tried to build G4Music (https://gitlab.gnome.org/neithern/g4music) following its instructions but I got many syntax errors.
[image]

As you can see GTK-4.0 is marked as not found. However I have installed GTK-4.4 dev packages.
I'm using RHEL 9 as distro and I have all the packages required:

- gtk4.x86_64
- gtk4-devel.x86_64
- libvala.x86_64
- libvala-devel.x86_64
- vala.x86_64
- gstreamer1.x86_64
- gstreamer1-devel.x86_64
- libadwaita-1

I read that **?** operator (question mark) is used to control null values and there's a lot of code using this operator.
I have no experience with Vala language.

Do I missing some libraries? Why Vala compiler throw errors for this operator?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the null conditional operator was introduced in [Vala 0.53.1](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vala/-/blob/main/NEWS#L363), which was tagged 20 August 2021. That's a development release, so you want Vala 0.54+ installed to compile this.

To learn more about the null conditional operator read the [merge request](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vala/-/merge_requests/90) and [issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vala/-/issues/522). Ideally the build system for g4music would check for the minimum version of the Vala compiler needed.